# クリックして、２つの要素を同時に変更したい。

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://uu-hokkaido.cedars.jp/renewal.shtml

こちらのサイトのメインビジュアルで、北海道の地図の上の札幌の上のピンクの丸をクリックすると、

・地図の左右にある８つの要素の変更。(これはできました。)
・北海道人気観光８エリアの文字を変更（これも変更したいです。）

をしたいです。

札幌の上のピンクの丸に、
onclick="show('sapporo')を入れて、

上記２つにclass="sapporo"にすると、
１つしか変更されませんでした。

試しに
・地図の左右にある８つの要素　class="sapporo"
・北海道人気観光８エリアの文字　class="sapporo2"　と分けて、

札幌の上のピンクの丸に、
onclick="show('sapporo','sapporo2')などいれると無効になりました。

札幌の上のピンクの丸をクリックすると、

・地図の左右にある８つの要素の変更。(これはできました。)
・北海道人気観光８エリアの文字を変更（これも変更したいです。）

これを２つ同時に変更したいのですが、わかる方ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: 「北海道人気観光８エリアの文字」とは、ページ上のどの要素のことを指していますか？また、「北海道人気観光８エリア」の文字を具体的にどのように変更したいのですか？

Comment: supaさま、いつもありがとうございます。「北海道人気観光８エリア」の文字は、メインビジュアルの北海道の地図の上になります。　　　　　　　地図上の札幌エリア（ピンクの丸）をクリックすると、「北海道人気観光８エリア」が「札幌・小樽完全観光ガイド」に代わるようにしたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポストされているようなので、情報共有の為、リンクしておきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/197853
teratailにはマルチポストした際の注意書きがあるようですので、ご覧になってはいかがでしょうか。
https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice

Comment: think49 さま、わざわざ、ご教授頂き、ありがとうございます。確認してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show` 関数にはどの要素を表示したいのかが引数として渡されるため、その値が札幌だった場合にのみ見出しのテキスト内容を `textContent` プロパティを用いて変更すれば良いと思います。

```js
function show(course) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".container_mainvisual > div[id]")
    .forEach(e => (e.style.visibility = "hidden"));
  document.getElementById(course).style.visibility = "visible";

  if (course === "sapporo") {
    document.querySelector(".hokkaido_guide").textContent = "札幌・小樽完全観光ガイド";
  }
}
```

Comment: supaさま、いつも本当にありがとうございます。おかげ様で出来ました。感謝致します。